# SDL2 with VSCode, Undefintions of structs example SDL_DisplayMode

Tags: c++

I am programming on a linux machine using SDL2. Most of the components of SDL2 work fine. But there is a specific instance in which Visual Studio Code marks structs as undefined. An example of this is the SDL_DisplayMode. The code still compiles and executes normally, but VSCode doesn't seem to mark it as correct.

A workaround I had found was by opening the SDL_Video.h as it seems to recognise the struct. But, it only works as long as both files are opened, as soon as the main file or SDL_Video.h closes, than it is regarded as an error again.

Example: Output from the hint of SDL_GetDisplayMode():

```
int SDL_GetDisplayMode(int displayIndex, int modeIndex, <error-type> *mode)
mode – an SDL_DisplayMode structure filled in with the mode at modeIndex
```

Get information about a specific display mode. The display modes are sorted in this priority: - width -> largest to smallest - height -> largest to smallest - bits per pixel -> more colors to fewer colors - packed pixel layout -> largest to smallest - refresh rate -> highest to lowest

It is reading the file, yet it is considering this specific struct as invalid.

I installed SDL2 from the package manager and use the following command to compile:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -lSDL2
```

Comment: Are you using the stock C++ extension? I suggest trying Clangd, which has been working better for me.

Comment: It's discouraged to put "solved" in the title. You should either post an answer below if you want to help other users with the same problem (and then click the checkmark next to it to mark the question as solved), or delete the question altogether if you don't think it'll help anyone else.